# Entity Framework 4.3 Hosted SQL Server No Database Create Permissions

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-4

My SQL Server is hosted by my hosting provider. This means that I don't have permission to recreate (or create) the database.

This is causing me a problem with EF 4 - it thinks the tables are missing, which they are. I think is caused by not being able to recreate the database.

To recap: developed locally, moving to hosted server for first time run, switched the connection string, run against the hosted server, error saying Invalid object name 'dbo.Products'.

I have permission to create anything else apart from the DB

Am I correct in this assumption and how do I work around this?

Comment: Just insert the tables yourself?  Use a local installation on your local computer, export the tables, then import them to your shared hosting.  Considering I know for fact this worked for me means you have no excuse for not doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF 4.3 you can use the Package Manager Console from the tools menu item in visual studio. This will allow you to use migrations to generate a DB script. More info here

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

You could of course create a drop and create script yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can create the database manually and set the Database.SetInitializer(null) or you could try the EF 5 RC. In the [release notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/05/15/ef5-release-candidate-available-on-nuget.aspx) you can read that they solved this issue.